# getting bean id of target class in advice

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I have a few classes that interact with databases (more than one).  Some classes are reused so for example "obs.table1" is used to interact with table1 in database "obs" while "ref.table1" is used to interact with table1 in database "ref".  These databases are at different URLs and each gets its own connection pool, etc...  obs.table1 and ref.table1 are both instances of MyTable1Class, defined in beans file.

I have a pointcut that intercepts calls to methods annotated with @Transactional or with a custom annotation @MyTablesAnnotation and have it set so those calls will all get routed into a @Around advice.

This all works and the flow through the advice is correct.

What I am trying to add is reporting on what is going on in there.  Currently I can tell where in there I am, but I can't tell if it was obs.table1 or ref.table1 object that got me there.

Is there a way to extract the bean id of the object on whose method the advice was invoked on?

ProceedingJoinPoint that is passed to the method the only thing I do with it is call a .proceed on it and the rest is just various checks and catches.  I see that I can get either the target class or proxy class out of it, but... not sure how to go from there to knowing what the bean id was.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly it is **not** recommended to depend on bean id as it creates tight coupling with framework.

To quote from [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanNameAware.html) *`Note that it is not usually recommended that an object depend on its bean name, as this represents a potentially brittle dependence on external configuration, as well as a possibly unnecessary dependence on a Spring API.`*

Now to answer your question yes it is possible to fetch the name of bean via `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAware`.

The class for which you require the bean name should implement it and spring will auto-magically inject the name of the bean. However there is a gotcha which you should be aware and is mentioned in docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanNameAware.html#setBeanName-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Took me a bit to understand how to use it but yes this is perfect.  I'm not worried about Spring dependency since the bean name is used for display purposes in a "here is what database is not working" display.

Comment: glad that I could be of help :)

Comment: @Smrtnik could you please explain how you succeeded in injecting the bean name in the advice?

Comment: @SumitJain sure, sorry, didn't see this until now.
Advice:
`@Around("dbAccessImplementationPointcut() && mypackagenamePointcut()")  
public Object checkForAccessiblityDbResult(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint)  
{  
    String tablename = joinPoint.getTarget().toString();  
    //... advice stuff  
    LOG.info("Able to talk to table: " + tablename"); //or other things relevant to the advice  
    //... advice stuff  
}`

Pointcuts:
`@Pointcut("@annotation(mypackaname.DatabaseAvailabilityRequired)")  
private void dbAccessImplementationPointcut()  
{/** don't care */  
}`

Comment: `@Pointcut("within(mypackagename)")  
private void mypackagenamePointcut()  
{/** don't care */  
}`

Then I have class in mypackagename for each table I interact with, and the class implements TargetClassAware.  The methods I want to apply the Around advice to are then also annotated with `@DatabaseAvailabilityRequired`.

Now any time one of them is called I also get a LOG of what's going on with that table (I can talk to it, I can't talk to it, whatever).

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to properly format carriage returns in comments.